# I need to hide entire sub-report based on a field value in the sub-report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a Jasper Report with a bunch of sub reports. I need to hide some of the sub-reports based on a specific row total within the sub report. In the screenshot example, "Sub Report 1" and "Sub Report 3" needs to be hidden based on the total of "Row 3" for "Sub Report 1" and "Row 1" for "Sub Report 3".

Any help on pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

[Example Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVMx5.png)

Comment: You can use printWhenExpression to conditionally hide subreports

Comment: Are you using the subreports with passed in Datasource? Or are you using the internal Datasource for the subreports with some parameters?